# In metal does one vertex shader complete before the next vertex shader executes?

Tags: vertex-shader, metal, vertex-buffer

Suppose a Metal vertex shader `A` updates a buffer `buf`. Also suppose I have a second vertex shader `B` that is encoded after `A`. Can `B` use the results in `buf` or is it possible that `B` will begin executing before `A` has finished, meaning the contents of the buffer are not ready?

Comment: Writes in one render command encoder are visible in the subsequent command encoder. There is no such guarantee at the draw call level.

Comment: Vertex shaders output points. You can also use them as an opportunity to generate data that will be interpolated by fragment shaders. You're not using them to write to buffers. What buffers are you writing to in a shader? How does your vertex shader update a buffer? Did you mean to ask about a compute shader instead of a vertex shader?

Comment: You can write to a device buffer from a vertex shader, just as you can in a compute shader. It seems I could save a little bit of overhead by updating some buffers in a vertex shader as opposed to writing a dedicated compute shader. Just not sure if the GPU begins processing the next draw command before finishing the prior draw command, thus making the contents of a device buffer that is updated from a vertex shader unpredictable. Apple docs do not seem to address this as of course it does not conform to the typical use of a vertex shader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second vertex shader `B` is free to execute before vertex shader `A` if they encoded in the same `MTLRenderCommandEncoder`. If you'd like to read the output of `A` in `B`, then they must be encoded by separate `MTLRenderCommandEncoder`'s.

Note, however, the same is **not** true of compute dispatches within a `MTLComputeCommandEncoder`. The [relevant part of the doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/Compute-Ctx/Compute-Ctx.html) states:

> ## Executing a Compute Command
>
> To encode a command to execute a compute
>   function, call the dispatchThreadgroups:threadsPerThreadgroup: method
>   of MTLComputeCommandEncoder and specify the threadgroup dimensions and
>   the number of threadgroups. You can query the threadExecutionWidth and
>   maxTotalThreadsPerThreadgroup properties of MTLComputePipelineState to
>   optimize the execution of the compute function on this device.
>
> For most efficient execution of the compute function, set the total number
>   of threads specified by the threadsPerThreadgroup argument to the
>   dispatchThreadgroups:threadsPerThreadgroup: method to a multiple of
>   threadExecutionWidth. The total number of threads in a threadgroup is
>   the product of the components of threadsPerThreadgroup:
>   threadsPerThreadgroup.width * threadsPerThreadgroup.height *
>   threadsPerThreadgroup.depth. The maxTotalThreadsPerThreadgroup
>   property specifies the maximum number of threads that can be in a
>   single threadgroup to execute this compute function on the device.
>
> **Compute commands are executed in the order in which they are encoded
>   into the command buffer. A compute command finishes execution when all
>   threadgroups associated with the command finish execution and all
>   results are written to memory. Because of this sequencing, the results
>   of a compute command are available to any commands encoded after it in
>   the command buffer.**
>
> To end encoding commands for a compute command encoder, call the endEncoding method of MTLComputeCommandEncoder.
>   After ending the previous command encoder, you can create a new
>   command encoder of any type to encode additional commands into the
>   command buffer.